# Hailstone Java Program

Tags: java

I am working on The hailstone sequence program in which the user picks a positive integer. If number is even, it will be divided by two. If the number is odd, it'll be multiplied it by three and added by one. The program will continue until the number is equal to 1. The program will also tell the user the amount of steps it took to reach 1.

The goal is to be done recursively, my issue is that I am unable to declare each step to the user as the calculation happens to the number, for e.g "number is so I divide by 2 and it = "

This is my code so far, any suggestions or alternatives will help.

Thanks

`import javax.swing*`

```
{
   public class hailstone {
   static int Count;
   static int HailstoneNumbers(int Num)
   output += (Num + " " ) ;
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output);

    if (Num == 1 && Count == 0) {
        return Count;

    }
    else if (Num == 1 && Count != 0) {
        //n-1
        Count++;
        return Count;
    }
    else if (Num % 2 == 0) {
        Count++;
        HailstoneNumbers(Num / 2);
    }
    else if (Num % 2 != 0) {
        Count++;
         HailstoneNumbers(3 * Num + 1);
    }
    return Count;


}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int Num = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("\n Enter a positive number"));
    int x;

    x = HailstoneNumbers(Num);


   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Number of Steps" + x );
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `HailstoneNumbers(Num / 2);`. If you want to do it recursively, the function must return itself at each step, eg `return HailstoneNumbers(Num / 2);`. Also, if you are modifying a global variable, then the recursivity is pointless. Here is an example:

```
int hailstone(int i, int steps) {
    steps++;
    if(i == 1) return steps;
    if(i % 2 == 0) return hailstone(i / 2, steps);
    else return hailstone(i * 3 + 1, steps);
}

// main function
x = hailstone(num, 0);
```

Note that by convention functions and variables shouldn't start with a capital letter unless they're `final`.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution. Simplified by putting the print statement in the method.  Also, user should not have to worry about initializing the step count so I overloaded the `collatz` method. Note:  The official name of this is the `Collatz Conjecture` so I named the methods accordingly.

```java
   public int collatz(int v) {
      return hail(v, 0);
   }

   private int collatz(int v, int count) {
      System.out.println(v);
      if (v != 1) {
         return hail((v & 1) == 1 ? v * 3 + 1
               : v / 2, count + 1);
      }
      return count;
   }
```